# Using URL rewrite with sub domains; download file fails

Tags: url, iis, url-rewrite-module

I currently have this rewrite URL rule in my web.config file

```
        <rule name="Rewrite to qa" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^qa.golfgameskeeper.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="qa/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

it works great, makes qa.golfgameskeeper.com/qa work like qa.golfgameskeeper.com
However, when I try to download a file from a sub-directory of qa it seems to get confused
http://qa.golfgameskeeper.com/apps/iOS will list the file, but will not allow me to download it.

Even when clicking one the link above the rule re-writes the link to
qa.golfgameskeeper.com/qa/apps/iOS (cut and paste will work, not clicking the link)

Is there a way to modify this rule to allow what I'm trying to do?  So, as I'm writing this I figured out what I am trying to do.

have
qa.golfgameskeeper.com -> qa.golfgameskeeper.com/qa (works)
and allow
qa.golfgameskeeper.com/apps/iOS to download the file without rewriting the URL twice (which is what I think it does).

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rule before your rewrite rule to match on the apps subdirectory and do nothing, basically skipping the rewrite rule.

```
<rule name="Skip apps" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^apps/(.*)" />
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule>
    //your rewrite rule here
</rule>
```